# Assign Set Class To HTML Table Created in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, class, html-table

I'm trying to use JavaScript to create a table based off the amount of rows from one table and amount of columns from another. When doing this, I want to assign the table a couple div id's and a table class in order to have the generated table line up on the right side of my employee table.

My problem is, when I create the table in JavaScript this way, I lose the scroll bars for the x and y axis of the table and it appears below the employee table. Scrolling the table is then done with the window scroll instead of having the table set and scrollable itself. I'm still new to HTML and JavaScript and I can't seem to find where I'm going wrong on my own. Here's my code and a JSFiddle for clarification:

```js
            var rows = document.getElementById('dayRow').getElementsByTagName("td").length;
            var cols = document.getElementById('employeeCol').getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
            var myTable = document.createElement('table');
            myTable.classList.add("tableTasks");
            var tr1 = null;
            var td1 = null;
            var text1 = null;
            for(let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
              tr1 = document.createElement('tr');
              for(let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                td1 = document.createElement('td');
                text1 = document. createTextNode('cell');
                td1.appendChild(text1);
                tr1.appendChild(td1);
              }
              myTable.appendChild(tr1);
            }
            document.body.appendChild(myTable);
```

```css
    .tableTasks {
      width:100%;
      margin-top:5px;
      empty-cells: show;
      height:1000px;
      line-height: 35px;
      width: 100px;
    }
    
    #table-wrapper-tasks {
      position: relative;
      width:81%;
      float:right;
    }
    
    #table-scroll-tasks {
      overflow-x: scroll;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      max-height: 522px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="table-wrapper-tasks">
        <div id="table-scroll-tasks">
          </div>
        </div>
```

I'm trying to get something like the image attached.[image: Test Desired Outcome]

https://jsfiddle.net/kk05x1cg/#&togetherjs=8kJlzomlvg

Comment: Do you have a snapshot of what you're trying to create? not following your question properly.

Comment: I attached one just now in an edit. I hope this helps, I'm sorry for my bad description.